# Indentation - XAML

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

Does anybody know how to do an auto-indent a XAML file in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: In addition to that, how does one format **attributes**, not just elements? (the latter being the easy part..)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With the document open, press

<kbd>CONTROL+K</kbd> <kbd>CONTROL+D</kbd>

Comment: All answers are correct but I preferred this one: I don't like to use the mouse while I need to type. Thanks everybody

Comment: If this keyboard command (or *Edit >> Advanced >> Format Document*) is not working on XAML code, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18206188/772086) StackOverflow answer: *Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> XAML >> Formatting >> Spacing >> and check “Position each attribute on a separate line”*

Comment: Cheers @Mike! This is the answer i was looking for! The default shortcut was not doing anything until i set it up from there!

Answer (score 5):

Menu - Edit:Advanced:Format Document (Your keyboard shortcut will be to the right of the menu item)

Comment: Is there any obvious reason why this wouldn't work for me? I get no change.

Answer (score 1):

I find that if I just close the current object using the auto-complete functionality Visual Studio will indent everything in-between.

So you could just delete the last line of your XAML and then just start retyping the start of the line, hit tab and get your XAML indented.

Or you could just select Edit > Advanced > Format Document.

Comment: All of the above doesn't properly re-indent XML attributes, though - just elements :-(

Comment: I guess it's because it assumes they have to be in the same line so if the user didn't put them in the same line, he's a heretic anyway.