# What is the hotkey for formatting XAML in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hotkeys

The hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works for formatting C# code only, but not for XAML for some reason. 
Does anybody know what the hotkey is for it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> work for me.

or Edit->Advanced->Format Document

Comment: I did Ctrl -K, Ctrl - D after doing ffonz suggestion below and it works now.

Answer (score 47):

Just as user2425056 my XAML wasn't formatting with all three options from devdigital.

The option I had to set to get a proper formatting is:
Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> XAML >> Formatting >> Spacing >> and check “Position each attribute on a separate line”

Answer (score 2):

My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> was not formating XAML until I went into
Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> XAML and made some changes. Then it started working!

Comment: Could you describe what changes you actually made?